# Reload the combo box after insert query?

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to reload the combo box so that it would display the values recently entered by me.
The Language used is C#.Net 2005..I am making a windows application. Please guide me?

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to call the method `.DataBind()` every time you want to "refresh" the combobox with new data

Comment: Thanx for your help!! The re-binding of the db helped me solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Save your last entered values, then load them when the comboBox is loaded. Something like:

```
private stirng _comboBoxSavedListPath = "";//or from application settings..

private List<string> _comboBoxLastEnteredValues = new List<string>();


private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//or whenever you want to save
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        string entry = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (!_comboBoxLastEnteredValues.Contains(entry))
        {
            _comboBoxLastEnteredValues.Add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Now handle the form `Closing` event or just save the list again whenever item added. and load the list whenever form is loaded:

```
private void form1_Closing..
{
    SaveList(_comboBoxLastEnteredValues);//Like(File.WriteAllLines(_comboBoxLastEnteredValues.ToArray(), _comboBoxSavedListPath);
}

private void form1_Load...
{
    _comboBoxLastEnteredValues = LoadLastSavedList();//Like File.ReadAllLines(_comboBoxSavedListPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help!! The re-binding of the db helped me solved my problem